# How do I manipulate an unstructured text data using stringr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, stringr, text-manipulation

I have an unstructured data which I hope to manipulate it so that it becomes a data that is usable for analysis.

The following is my dataframe which contains 97 observations and 5 variables, namely, `DRUG_NAME`, `DRUG_STRENGTH_NO`, `DRUG_STRENGTH_UNIT`, `INSTRUCTIONS` and `EXPANDED_INSTRUCTIONS`.

```
df <- structure(list(DRUG_NAME = c("ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", 
"ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", 
"ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", 
"CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", 
"CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", 
"CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", 
"CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", 
"CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", "CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", 
"CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", "CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", 
"CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", "CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", 
"CALCIUM CARB 625MG TABLET", "CALCIUM CARB 625MG TABLET", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", 
"HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", "HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", 
"HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", "HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET", 
"SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET", "SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET", "SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET", 
"SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET"), DRUG_STRENGTH_NO = c(0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 667, 667, 667, 667, 667, 667, 667, 
667, 667, 667, 667, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 
625, 625, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 
4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25), DRUG_STRENGTH_UNIT = c("MCG", 
"MCG", "MCG", "MCG", "MCG", "MCG", "MCG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", 
"IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", 
"IU", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG"), INSTRUCTIONS = c("0.25MCG BIW NR", 
"0.25mcg om", "0.25MCG tiw", "0.25MCG TIW NR", "1 BIW NR", "1 OM", 
"1 TIW", "1 2T", "1 3T", "1 3T WITH MEALS", "1 BD", "1 TDS WITH MEALS", 
"1TAB 3T", "1TAB 3T", "1TAB 3T", "1TAB 3T", "1TAB 3T", "2TAB 3T", 
"1 3T", "1 3t nr", "1 3T WITH MEALS", "1 OM & 2 OA & 2 ON", "1.25G 3T", 
"1.25G 3T", "1.25G 3T NR", "1250MG OM", "2 OM", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1 BIW", "1 BIW NR", "1 EOW", "1 EOW", "1 oi", "1 once", 
"1 TAD", "1 TAD", "4000UNIT BIW", "4000UNIT BIW NR", "4000UNIT EOW", 
"4000UNIT OIW", "USE AS DIRECTED.", "(blank)", "1 2T", "1 2T", 
"1 OM", "2 2T", "2 2T NR", "200MG 2T", "200MG 2T NR", "200MG BD", 
"200MG OM", "200MG OM", "200MG TIW", "200MG TIW nr", "400MG 2T", 
"400MG 2T", "400MG 2T NR", "400mg bd", "400MG OM", "1 2T", "1 OM", 
"1 OM", "1 OM PRN", "1.5 2t", "2 2T", "20MG OM", "20MG OM", "20MG OM", 
"40MG 2T", "40MG 2T", "40mg od", "40MG OM", "60MG 2T", "60mg bd", 
"80mg 3t", ".5 om", "0.5 OM", "12.5MG 2T", "12.5MG OM", "12.5MG OM NR", 
"1 2T", "1 3T", "1000MG 3T", "1G TDS", "2 3t", "500MG 2T", "500MG 2T NR", 
"500MG 3T", "500mg tds", "1 OM", "1 OM NR", "12.5MG OM", "12.5MG OM", 
"25MG OM"), EXPANDED_INSTRUCTIONS = c("TAKE ONE TABLET TWICE WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE TABLET TWICE WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", "TAKE ONE TABLET TWICE DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY (WITH MEALS)", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY on meals", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY with meals, started on 16/4/2010", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING AND TWO TABLETS EVERY AFTERNOON AND TWO TABLETS EVERY NIGHT", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE TWO TABLETS EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS EVERY MORNING", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY 10 DAYS", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY 10 DAYS.", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY 2 WEEKS.", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY TWO WEEKS", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE TWICE WEEKLY", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE TWICE WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY FORTNIGHTLY", "INJECT ONE SYRINGE EVERY FORTNIGHTLY", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE ONCE EVERY TEN DAYS", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE ONCE EVERY 10 DAYS", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE AS DIRECTED (ONCE EVERY 10 DAYS)", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE AS DIRECTED EVERY 10 DAYS", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE TWICE WEEKLY", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE TWICE WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY FORTNIGHTLY", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE ONCE WEEKLY", 
"USE AS DIRECTED. ONCE EVERY 10 DAYS", "INSERT ONE SYRINGE EVERY 10 DAYS AS DIRECTED", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY [STOP 2 WEEKS PRIOR TO COLONOSCOPY]", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE TABLET TWICE DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING REDUCE. STOP AT NEXT TCU", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY", "TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY TAKE DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE TWO TABLETS TWICE DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING prn for leg swelling", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING WHEN NECESSARY FOR LEG SWELLING", 
"TAKE ONE AND A HALF TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING DOSE DECREASED ON 08 10 2015", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING started 9/11/12 for edema/ Decreased enalapril 9/11/12", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY Dose decreased on 27/1/2010. stop span K", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET ONCE DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE ONE AND A HALF TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE AND A HALF TABLETS TWICE DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE HALF TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"TAKE ONE CAPSULE 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE CAPSULE 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO CAPSULES 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE TWO CAPSULES THREE TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO CAPSULES 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE CAPSULE 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE CAPSULE 2 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE CAPSULE 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE CAPSULE THREE TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING NEW, STARTED ON 20/4/15,", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -97L), .Names = c("DRUG_NAME", 
"DRUG_STRENGTH_NO", "DRUG_STRENGTH_UNIT", "INSTRUCTIONS", "EXPANDED_INSTRUCTIONS"
))
```

I would like to calculate the **total dosage per day or per week or per fortnight or per month**, depending on the variable, `EXPANDED_INSTRUCTIONS`. This value would be obtained by multiplying the drug strength by no. of tablet/capsule/syringe by frequency.

1. If we have a patient that was prescribed "ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB" and instructed to "TAKE ONE TABLET TWICE WEEKLY", then his total dosage per week is 0.5MCG
2. If medication is "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)" and instruction is "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY 10 DAYS", then dosage per month is 12000IU.
3. If medication is "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)" and instruction is "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY FORTNIGHTLY", then dosage per fortnight is 4000IU.

My desired dataframe is as follows:

```
structure(list(DRUG_NAME = c("ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", 
"ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", 
"ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "ALPHACALCIDOL 0.25MCG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", 
"CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", 
"CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", 
"CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", 
"CALCIUM ACETATE 667MG TAB", "CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", 
"CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", "CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", 
"CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", "CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", 
"CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", "CALCIUM CARB 1250MG CHEWABLE TAB", 
"CALCIUM CARB 625MG TABLET", "CALCIUM CARB 625MG TABLET", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", 
"ERYTHROPOIETIN ALFA 4,000 IU INJ (EPREX)", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", "FERROUS FUMARATE 200MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", 
"FUROSEMIDE 40MG TABLET", "HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", 
"HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", "HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", 
"HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", "HYDROCHLOROTHIAZIDE 25MG TABLET", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", 
"SODIUM BICARBONATE 500MG CAP", "SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET", 
"SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET", "SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET", "SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET", 
"SPIRONOLACTONE 25MG TABLET"), DRUG_STRENGTH_NO = c(0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 667, 667, 667, 667, 667, 667, 667, 
667, 667, 667, 667, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 
625, 625, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 
4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25), DRUG_STRENGTH_UNIT = c("MCG", 
"MCG", "MCG", "MCG", "MCG", "MCG", "MCG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", 
"IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", 
"IU", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", 
"MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG"), INSTRUCTIONS = c("0.25MCG BIW NR", 
"0.25mcg om", "0.25MCG tiw", "0.25MCG TIW NR", "1 BIW NR", "1 OM", 
"1 TIW", "1 2T", "1 3T", "1 3T WITH MEALS", "1 BD", "1 TDS WITH MEALS", 
"1TAB 3T", "1TAB 3T", "1TAB 3T", "1TAB 3T", "1TAB 3T", "2TAB 3T", 
"1 3T", "1 3t nr", "1 3T WITH MEALS", "1 OM & 2 OA & 2 ON", "1.25G 3T", 
"1.25G 3T", "1.25G 3T NR", "1250MG OM", "2 OM", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1 BIW", "1 BIW NR", "1 EOW", "1 EOW", "1 oi", "1 once", 
"1 TAD", "1 TAD", "4000UNIT BIW", "4000UNIT BIW NR", "4000UNIT EOW", 
"4000UNIT OIW", "USE AS DIRECTED.", "(blank)", "1 2T", "1 2T", 
"1 OM", "2 2T", "2 2T NR", "200MG 2T", "200MG 2T NR", "200MG BD", 
"200MG OM", "200MG OM", "200MG TIW", "200MG TIW nr", "400MG 2T", 
"400MG 2T", "400MG 2T NR", "400mg bd", "400MG OM", "1 2T", "1 OM", 
"1 OM", "1 OM PRN", "1.5 2t", "2 2T", "20MG OM", "20MG OM", "20MG OM", 
"40MG 2T", "40MG 2T", "40mg od", "40MG OM", "60MG 2T", "60mg bd", 
"80mg 3t", ".5 om", "0.5 OM", "12.5MG 2T", "12.5MG OM", "12.5MG OM NR", 
"1 2T", "1 3T", "1000MG 3T", "1G TDS", "2 3t", "500MG 2T", "500MG 2T NR", 
"500MG 3T", "500mg tds", "1 OM", "1 OM NR", "12.5MG OM", "12.5MG OM", 
"25MG OM"), EXPANDED_INSTRUCTIONS = c("TAKE ONE TABLET TWICE WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE TABLET TWICE WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", "TAKE ONE TABLET TWICE DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY (WITH MEALS)", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY on meals", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY with meals, started on 16/4/2010", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING AND TWO TABLETS EVERY AFTERNOON AND TWO TABLETS EVERY NIGHT", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY WITH MEALS", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE TWO TABLETS EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS EVERY MORNING", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY 10 DAYS", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY 10 DAYS.", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY 2 WEEKS.", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY TWO WEEKS", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE TWICE WEEKLY", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE TWICE WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY FORTNIGHTLY", "INJECT ONE SYRINGE EVERY FORTNIGHTLY", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE ONCE EVERY TEN DAYS", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE ONCE EVERY 10 DAYS", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE AS DIRECTED (ONCE EVERY 10 DAYS)", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE AS DIRECTED EVERY 10 DAYS", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE TWICE WEEKLY", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE TWICE WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE EVERY FORTNIGHTLY", "INJECT CONTENTS OF ONE SYRINGE ONCE WEEKLY", 
"USE AS DIRECTED. ONCE EVERY 10 DAYS", "INSERT ONE SYRINGE EVERY 10 DAYS AS DIRECTED", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY [STOP 2 WEEKS PRIOR TO COLONOSCOPY]", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE TABLET TWICE DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING REDUCE. STOP AT NEXT TCU", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY", "TAKE ONE TABLET THREE TIMES WEEKLY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY TAKE DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE TWO TABLETS TWICE DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING prn for leg swelling", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING WHEN NECESSARY FOR LEG SWELLING", 
"TAKE ONE AND A HALF TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE TWO TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING DOSE DECREASED ON 08 10 2015", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING started 9/11/12 for edema/ Decreased enalapril 9/11/12", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY Dose decreased on 27/1/2010. stop span K", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET ONCE DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE ONE AND A HALF TABLETS 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE AND A HALF TABLETS TWICE DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO TABLETS 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE HALF TABLET 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", "TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING (NON-REFUNDABLE)", 
"TAKE ONE CAPSULE 2 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE CAPSULE 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO CAPSULES 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE TWO CAPSULES THREE TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE TWO CAPSULES 3 TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE CAPSULE 2 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE CAPSULE 2 TIMES DAILY (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE ONE CAPSULE 3 TIMES DAILY", 
"TAKE ONE CAPSULE THREE TIMES DAILY", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING (NON-REFUNDABLE)", "TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING", 
"TAKE HALF TABLET EVERY MORNING NEW, STARTED ON 20/4/15,", "TAKE ONE TABLET EVERY MORNING"
), TOTAL_DOSAGE = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 1334, 
2001, 2001, 1334, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 4002, 3750, 
3750, 3750, 6250, 3750, 3750, 3750, 1250, 1250, 12000, 12000, 
4000, 4000, 8000, 8000, 4000, 4000, 12000, 12000, 12000, 12000, 
8000, 8000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 12000, 400, 400, 200, 800, 800, 
400, 400, 400, 200, 200, 600, 600, 800, 800, 800, 800, 400, 80, 
40, 40, 40, 120, 160, 20, 20, 20, 80, 80, 40, 40, 120, 120, 240, 
12.5, 12.5, 25, 12.5, 12.5, 1000, 1500, 3000, 3000, 3000, 1000, 
1000, 1500, 1500, 25, 25, 12.5, 12.5, 25), PER = c("WEEK", "DAY", 
"WEEK", "WEEK", "WEEK", "DAY", "WEEK", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", 
"DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", 
"DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "MONTH", "MONTH", 
"FORTNIGHT", "FORTNIGHT", "WEEK", "WEEK", "FORTNIGHT", "FORTNIGHT", 
"MONTH", "MONTH", "MONTH", "MONTH", "WEEK", "WEEK", "FORTNIGHT", 
"WEEK", "MONTH", "MONTH", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", 
"DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "WEEK", "WEEK", "DAY", "DAY", 
"DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", 
"DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", 
"DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", 
"DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", "DAY", 
"DAY", "DAY")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -97L), .Names = c("DRUG_NAME", 
"DRUG_STRENGTH_NO", "DRUG_STRENGTH_UNIT", "INSTRUCTIONS", "EXPANDED_INSTRUCTIONS", 
"TOTAL_DOSAGE", "PER"))
```

I have written my own code, which works fine except for observations 22 and 44 where the first patient took different numbers of tablets at different times of the day while the other has an instruction that indicated "ONCE" instead of "ONE SYRINGE".

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(rebus)
```

I listed the frequencies (`freq`) and drug quantities (`drug_form_qty`) as vectors:

```
freq <- c("EVERY MORNING", "EVERY AFTERNOON", "EVERY NIGHT", 
          "ONCE DAILY", "TWICE DAILY", "THRICE DAILY",
          "2 TIMES DAILY", "3 TIMES DAILY", 
          "TWO TIMES DAILY", "THREE TIMES DAILY",
          "ONCE WEEKLY", "TWICE WEEKLY", 
          "TWO TIMES WEEKLY", "THREE TIMES WEEKLY", 
          "EVERY FORTNIGHTLY", "EVERY 2 WEEKS", "EVERY TWO WEEKS",
          "EVERY TEN DAYS", "EVERY 10 DAYS")
drug_form_qty <- c("HALF TABLET", "ONE TABLET", "ONE AND A HALF TABLETS", "TWO TABLETS", 
                   "ONE CAPSULE", "TWO CAPSULES", "ONE SYRINGE")
```

Then, I created new variables called `DRUG_FORM_QTY` that extract the number of tablets, capsules etc. and `FREQ`, that extract the frequency (i.e. every morning, twice daily, every 10 days etc.). Next, I changed the above-mentioned variables into numerics, `DRUG_FORM_QTY_NO` and `FREQ_NO`. To know if it is per day, week, fortnight or month, I included a new variable, `PER` to contain this information. The `TOTAL_DOSAGE` is calculated by taking `DRUG_STRENGTH_NO*DRUG_FORM_QTY_NO*FREQ_NO`.

```
df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(DRUG_FORM_QTY = str_extract(EXPANDED_INSTRUCTIONS, pattern = or1(drug_form_qty)),
         FREQ = str_extract(EXPANDED_INSTRUCTIONS, pattern = or1(freq)),
         DRUG_FORM_QTY_NO = case_when(
           str_detect(DRUG_FORM_QTY, "ONE AND A HALF") ~ 1.5,
           str_detect(DRUG_FORM_QTY, "HALF") ~ 0.5,
           str_detect(DRUG_FORM_QTY, "ONE") ~ 1,
           str_detect(DRUG_FORM_QTY, "TWO") ~ 2),
         FREQ_NO = case_when(
           str_detect(FREQ, or1(c("TEN DAYS", "10 DAYS"))) ~ 3,
           str_detect(FREQ, or1(c("EVERY", "ONCE"))) ~ 1,
           str_detect(FREQ, or1(c("TWICE", "2 TIMES", "TWO TIMES"))) ~ 2,
           str_detect(FREQ, or1(c("THRICE", "3 TIMES", "THREE TIMES"))) ~ 3),
         PER = case_when(
           str_detect(FREQ, or1(c("EVERY MORNING", "EVERY AFTERNOON", "EVERY NIGHT", "DAILY"))) ~ "DAY",
           str_detect(FREQ, "WEEKLY") ~ "WEEK",
           str_detect(FREQ, or1(c("FORTNIGHTLY", "2 WEEKS"))) ~ "FORTNIGHT",
           str_detect(FREQ, or1(c("TEN DAYS", "10 DAYS"))) ~ "MONTH"),
         TOTAL_DOSAGE = DRUG_STRENGTH_NO*DRUG_FORM_QTY_NO*FREQ_NO)
```

I would like to get alternatives or efficient ways to get my desired dataframe above. Thank you.

Comment: the data is incredibly messy (as you would expect for user data). There are always going to be edge cases of incorrectly inputted information, if you don't validate the inputs.

Comment: The way you have done it is probably the best way it can be done. I would do it similarly, but instead of having everything within a mutate call, I would break out the instruction parser into it's own function, and then run the instruction parser on each line